# openliteserver: https redirect not working

Tags: ubuntu, https, server, digital-ocean, openlitespeed

I am following the tutorial outlined [here](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/images/wordpress/#enable-https) to setup https redirect and when I visit the normal site I hit the litespeed server page you get when you first spin up the droplet. When you prefix the url with https:// it goes to the proper wordpress landing page. This is the current rewrite rule for the domain.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

(example is not the actual domain)

What am I missing

Comment: you need to add this line to the default vhost , not the wordpress vhost

Comment: What does the default host file settings look like? I deleted it as I thought it was causing the issue.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urnHwEQ2eAE&ab_channel=LiteSpeedTechnologies     check how to create a vhost to covert the IP or non-matched domain